# How to insert a value in a cell on the same row that a duplicate value changes in a column

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I'm working on a code that will enter in "total" in column J at the row in which a cell value changes under column B (column J is entirely blank). For example, if B16 = "Vendor A" and then B17 = "Vendor B" I would want the value "total" in cell J16 to represent the total amount that Vendor A has sold. The vendors list on column B starts on cell B13 but the last row is dynamic and changes every month.

Is there a way I can make it so that at everytime the value changes in column B, the corresponding cell in column J will have the value of "total"

[image: please see image for the layout of my worksheet]

I also need to sum all the amounts of vendor A to the right of where total is located, so bonus points if you can figure that out...I'm still working on how to bring in "Total"
Thank you!!

Please see below for my code:

```
 Dim startrow As Long
 Dim lastrow As Long
 
 '12 represents header rows. 13 is where data start
 startrow = 12 
 lastrow = .Cells(.rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("vendortotals")    
 
 For i = startrow + 1 To lastrow + 1

 'attempt to add total

  If Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
     If Cells(i, 2) <> Cells(i + 1, 2) Then
        Cells(i, 10).Values = "Total"
     End If
  End If
```

Comment: I guess you have a datasheet of vendors, product, sales etc.  If so, you can use pivot table utility to get totals, subtotals, groupings, formattings etc.  One step further you may consider moving your data to Access and solving puzzles like this in report functionality of Access.  I have a feeling that you are seeking the answers in wrong ways/places.

Comment: I just made up an example that i thought would be easier to digest. My datasheet is unrelated to that and needs to be in excel.

Answer (score 0):

Yay! I thought it wasn't working earlier and it's because i had the cell range incorrectly. This works if im trying to enter "total" in column J. Additionally, update Values to Value

```
If Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
    If Cells(i, 2) <> Cells(i + 1, 2) Then
        Cells(i, 10).Value = "Total"
    End If
End If
```

Comment: `Cells(i, 2)` is a range. Although its default property is `Value`, you may end up with unexpected results (errors) relying on it. You are comparing values, so it is good practice to use `.Value` in the other two lines, too: `If Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" Then` and `If Cells(i, 2).Value <> Cells(i + 1, 2).Value Then`.